# PHP Form Question

Tags: php

Is there a way I can check if a user enters a `<p>` tag inside a form using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

If it is posted, you can do something like strstr of '<p>' or one of the similar functions, which will then return the location if it exists or NULL if it doesn't.

```
<?php if ( strstr ( $body, '<p>' ) == NULL )
echo 'All Clear';
else die ( 'Contains <p>' );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(empty($_POST['foo'])) {
   print "Foo empty";
} else { 
   if(stristr($_POST['foo'], '<p>')) {
      print "Contains P tag";
   } else {
      print "No P tag";
   }
}
```

Comment: Before doing this, you'd want to check that isset($_POST['foo']); is true, else you'll get an undefined index notice.

Comment: use the strifoo functions to catch both <P> and <p>.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to strip all markup use:

```
strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

otherwise:

```
substr_replace ( $string , string $replacement , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

Depends on *why* you what to know

1 - [PHP.net](http://us.php.net)

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript or jquery .onFocus event.

Comment: I really would like to use PHP.

Comment: ahh I see. I assumed you wanted to know when a control inside the <p> tag was in focus or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they don't enter anything fancy like `<p class="stuff">`, you can use a simple `strpos()` call:

```
$text = $_POST['name_of_field'];
if (strpos($text, '<p>') !== FALSE) {
    die("No <p> tags allowed");
}
```

If they enter attributes, then you'd most likely need a regex, which has its own basket of problems:

```
$text = $_POST['name_of_field'];
if (preg_match('/<p.*?>/i', $text)) {
   die("No <p> tags allowed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? Assuming you have the form content in a string variable, something like this should work:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$string1 = 'Hello <p> world';
$string2 = 'Hello world';

$foundIt1 = strripos($string1, '<p>');
$foundIt2 = strripos($string2, '<p>');

if (false === $foundIt1) {
    echo '1. didn\'t find it';
} else {
    echo "1. found it at offset $foundIt1";
}
echo "\n";

if (false === $foundIt2) {
    echo '2. didn\'t find it';
} else {
    echo "2. found it at offset $foundIt2";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace or remove them:

```
$new_data = preg_replace("/<p>/", "whatever you want to replace it with here", $_POST['form_field_id_here']);
```

If you just want to check for them

```
strpos("<p>", $_POST['form_field_id_here']);
```

Then read this to make sure you aren't leaving your site open to attackers:
[What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

(Edit: I know, I know. No regex for HTML parsing. IMHO, if all you are doing is checking for

tags then a little bit of regex is better than using a huge HTML parser. That said, if you are checking for many tags and things like `<p class="something">` then you should look at this: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php )